# Using lambda with generic type in Scala

Tags: scala, function, generics, lambda

The second argument of `myFunc` is a function with complex arguments:

```
def myFunc(list : List[String],
           combine: (Map[String, ListBuffer[String]], String, String) => Unit) = {
    // body of myFunc is just a stub and doesn't matter
    val x = Map[String, ListBuffer[String]]()

    list.foreach ((e:String) => {
       val spl = e.split(" ")
       combine(x, spl(0), spl(1))
    })

    x
}
```

I need to pass second argument to `myFunc`, so it can be used with various types `A, B` instead of specific `String, ListBuffer[String]`.

```
def myFunc(list : List[A], combine: (Map[A, B], A, A) => Unit) = {

    val x = Map[A, B]()

    list.foreach(e => {          
        combine(x, e)
    })
}
```

How to declare and call such construct?

Comment: You need to specify that A and B are type parameters, like this: `def myFunc[A, B](list: List[A], combine: (Map[A, B], A, A) => Unit)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following,

```
def myFunc[A, B](list : List[A], combine: (Map[A, B], A, A) => Unit) = {
  val x = Map[A, B]()
  list.foreach (e => combine(x, e, e))
  x
}
```

Ad use it like

```
myFunc[String, Int](List("1","2","3"), (obj, k, v) => obj.put(k, v.toInt) )
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking to generalise the container being used. Were you looking for something like this? Here we import `scala.language.higherKinds` so that we can take `Container`, a kind which takes a single type parameter as a type parameter to `addPair`.

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

def addPair[K, V, Container[_]](map: Map[K, Container[V]],
                                addToContainer: (Container[V], V) => Container[V],
                                emptyContainer: => Container[V],
                                pair: (K, V)): Map[K, Container[V]] = {
    val (key, value) = pair
    val existingValues = map.getOrElse(key, emptyContainer)
    val newValues = addToContainer(existingValues, value)

    map + (key -> newValues)
}
```